# Trouble setting currentSchema for DB2 on Glassfish

Tags: jdbc, glassfish, db2

I've been working to move an application from MySQL to DB2, and am currently running into trouble with currentSchema on deployment.

The query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE BooleanColumn=1
```

will give me an error ( SQLCODE=-204) which means the object doesn't exist.

If instead I issue the query like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM SCHEMA.SomeTable  WHERE BooleanColumn=1
```

Everything works as I would expect.

It seems like I should be able to set this to default to a schema somewhere, and at this point I have focused on the JDBC connection pool in Glassfish.  It seems like I would usually be able to build a JDBC URL something like "jdbc:db2://SERVER_NAME:PORT/DATABASE:currentSchema=SCHEMA_NAME;", and currentSchema would take care of my needs, but I don't know how to do that in the admin control for Glassfish.  I obviously don't know a lot about Glassfish - it is very likely I am looking in the wrong place.

I have the "Additional Properties" portion configured something like this:

Blah.  I guess I'm too new to embed pictures...this link is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqUQd.jpg

Any help in getting this setup would be great...I don't want to have to hunt down every table reference and preface it with the schema name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can issue [this statement](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001016.html) in the same connection:

```
SET SCHEMA = my_schema;
```

By default, DB2 uses your username as the schema.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm calling this immediately after creating each connection and it works perfectly.

Comment: Seems like a dirty workaround. Is there a way to set this in glassfish itself?